# How to start multiple node/socket servers on one machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am starting two different node servers, on different ports, but I still get the following error.

```
info  - socket.io started
info  - FlashPolicyFileServer received an error event:
    listen EADDRINUSE
```

This is how I am starting the first server:

```
"use strict";

var 
    express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express();

// set some config vars

var 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    socket = require('./app/lib/socket');

// these settings are common to both environments
app.configure(function () {
    // configuration left out
    app.use(app.router);

});

//  Load the routing
require('./app/routes')(app);
// run the server with socket.io
server.listen(3001);
socket.listen(server, session, app);
```

I am starting the second server the exact same way  except the second last line is changed to :

```
server.listen(3002);
```

socket.io is started like this in another file

```
exports.listen = function (server, sessionStore, app) {
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    ...
```

Not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: I've never run into this problem personally but it would appear that it's the flash policy server started by socket.io which is the problem.  If you're not using the flash transport, or if you were to run your own policy server, you could disable it.  Otherwise you could configure its port for each app, or according to the docs, pass -1 as the policy server port option to tell the flash client to connect over the same port as the app.  More info can be found in the socket.io wiki [configuring section](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash policy port defaults to 10843, so both apps will try to run it off this port, which is the error you are getting. Either remove the transport, or set the port using

```
io.set('flash policy port', 3005)
```

Or you can just remove that transport altogether:

```
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket',
    'xhr-polling',
    'htmlfile',
    'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Comment: Well, the reasoning is explained in @numbers1311407 's comment. If someone leaves the answer in a comment, feel free to just use that in your answer; it's free rep!

Comment: @forivall I would have if I had seen the comment :)